# Eddystone URL discovery on Progressive web apps

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon, progressive-web-apps, eddystone-url

consider a restaurant, what if an already opened PWA using eddystone URL Pushed through Eddystone URL using physical web by a beacon needs to identify table in a restaurant  according to the beacon attached to table transmitting signal.
 I found requestdevice and requestLEScan but they helped in pairing not displaying notification/content/trigger event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking a progressive web app to a beacon to trigger a event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472935/linking-a-progressive-web-app-to-a-beacon-to-trigger-a-event)

Answer (score 0):

Eddystone-URL beacons could only do is transmit the URL. The mobile device is only detecting these signals only when a user has swiped down on their notification bar. When the user has tapped on it, that's the only time they are taken (take note of keyword: taken) to the site. There is no connection between the mobile device and the beacon unless you create a backend service that connects the site and the mobile device through service workers.

PWA is not an app, its still a website that utilises the modern web technologies (if supported by the browser). The notifications are passive notifications meaning, users will only notice it if they need it. It will not vibrate nor give an audible sound when you are near one unless you build an app for this. This is why they came up with this method because app notifications were already intrusive.